# python program to overload ‘==’ operator to print the details of students having same marks

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Here I have to create a class student with following member attributes: roll no, name, age and total marks. Create suitable methods for reading and printing member variables also to overload ‘==’ operator to print the details of students having same marks. Here I can't find way how to overload == operator for marks. Here I have got error.

```
class Student():


    def __init__(self,r_no,name,age,marks):
        self.r_no = r_no
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.marks = marks


    def displayStudent(self):
        print ("Roll no : ", self.r_no, "Name : ", self.name,  ", Age: ", self.age,  ", Marks: ", self.marks)


    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1},{3},{4})".format(self.r_no,self.name,self.age,self.marks)

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if(self.marks==other.marks):
            return self.marks==other.marks


stu = []

for i in range (1,3):
    print("Enter Details for Students %d" % (i))
    r_no = int(input("Enter Roll no:"))
    name = input("Enter Name:")
    age = int(input("Enter Age:"))
    marks = input("Enter Marks:")
    stu.append(Student(r_no,name,age,marks))



for s in stu:
    s.displayStudent()
```

Comment: `Student(marks)` what is the point of this line? What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: @Lafexlos I think if he is using an interactive viewer it is basically a call to print. for example, issuing a command in ipython without the print function displays the result of the function.

Comment: What is your error? I think that would be helpful to know.

Comment: @d_kennetz Code shown, uses `Student(..)` in consecutive lines where one is correct and one is not. That's why I asked for the reasoning.

Comment: I have no idea about how to overload the == operator for the same for marks for all the students so that i have written student(marks) but i have also realized that it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To report that two students are equal given that they have the same marks the `__eq__` function should look like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.marks == other.marks
```

It returns `True` if the marks are the same and `False` otherwise

Then this code returns `True` and `False` respectively.

```
print(Student(1, 'test1', 20, 4) == Student(2, 'test2', 30, 4))  # True
print(Student(3, 'test3', 0, 1) == Student(3, 'test3', 0, 2))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go6XF.png)

Instead of `def __eq__`, you need to use an `if` condition, like

```
if(stu[0].marks==stu[1].marks):
      print("marks of ",stu[0].name,"&",stu[1].name," is same")
else:
      print("not same")
```

Or, if you have more data than just two students, you can use a `for` loop as well. For more details, check out the image I've linked at the top here.